# Collection of images for teaching children and disabled or cognitive impaired users clothes folding techniques

Tags: print-design, information-graphics, graphic-styles, chart-design, accessibility

I am not sure whether this post would be better suited for the Home Improvement stack exchange.

I am looking for sequences of info graphics for how to fold clothes, illustrating both of the following:

- all the different steps required in folding, including configurations of the body positions during folding and presence of support objects
- different ways of folding the same piece of clothes

This should be useful to young learners and people with cognitive impairment, as well as various physical impairments, and novices alike.

The clothes items should be t-shirts, sweaters, undershirts, skirts, socks, stockings, underwear, jeans and pants, and so forth.

I have seen a few posts on Instagram, but they seemed to be aimed at showing how to do things quickly, and with skill (skill, that most novice users, won't have).

The charts should also be useful to children that have trouble learning from their parents or teachers.

Thank you for your support.

It is very valuable.

I will be very thankful for your posta, and I'm sure that anyone reading those, can also give back, by putting into practice, and impressing upon others what they face learned.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Sorry, this appears off-topic to me. I don't know that it would fit on *any* stack. It's essentially a "google it for me" question. (if, by chance, your'e asking for someone to *make* such a thing... that is absolutely off-topic. Requests for free work are very frowned upon.)

Answer (score 2):

Besides maybe getting images off Wikihow, I would simply suggest hiring an illustrator on Upwork to draw what you need. Drawing isn't easy and with many specific requests like this "just hire a professional who can do a good job" is the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have luck looking at some the major stock photo and stock illustration agencies. Adobe, Getty, Shutterstock, and others, all license illustrations as well as photographs. You may find series of vector drawings from which you can choose the ones you want.

Many illustrations are royalty-free, available for use with only a download fee. Others have royalties based on use, if you are a non-profit there may be special royalty categories you could benefit from.